# How to change keyboard language in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I just want to change keyboard language programmatically in flutter us there any package or solution available.

Comment: [Set the default language in a Flutter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610200/set-the-default-language-in-a-flutter-application)

Comment: Can you plz tell me how

Comment: @DarshanKhadse Did you find any solution? I am working on a Flutter Web App, and my requirement to type in Hindi language.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard language is based on your device's language or the keyboard itself you can't change the keyboard language automatically. What you can do is you can change the whole language of the app according to the system or the user can auto-select the language of the app its called localization/internationalization. There are a lot of packages available for it over [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev)

Comment: But in dictionary apps language is changed each time you switch the direction